# The Server Instance cannot be started because the Integrated Weblogic domain was not built successfully.-jdeveloper

Tags: jdeveloper

I am having jdeveloper 11.1.1.6.
I created domain named "jdev_domain" successfully.
I created simple application in jdeveloper and deploy it using **integratedweblogicserver**.The deployment finished successfully. But while I am running that application it throws following error:

> The Server Instance cannot be started because the Integrated Weblogic domain was not built successfully.

The extensions log is:

> Warning: Classpath entry
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\jdeveloper\was\com.ibm.ws.admin.client_7.0.0.jar
>   not found. Warning: Classpath entry
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\jdeveloper\was\com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient_7.0.0.jar
>   not found. Warning: Classpath entry
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\jdeveloper\was\com.ibm.ws.jpa.thinclient_7.0.0.jar
>   not found. Warning: Classpath entry
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\jdeveloper\was\com.ibm.ws.orb_7.0.0.jar not
>   found. Warning: Classpath entry
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\jdeveloper\was\ejb3exceptions.jar not found.
>   Warning: Classpath entry
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\jdeveloper\was\ibmorb.jar not found. Warning:
>   Classpath entry
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\jdeveloper\was\oracle.webservices.standalone.client.jar
>   not found. Warning: Classpath entry
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\jdeveloper\was\tools.jar not found. Warning:
>   Classpath entry
>   C:\Oracle\Middleware\jdeveloper\was\wsclient_extended.jar not found.

Eventhough there is errorlog, as I am beginner I don't know how to solve it. Please solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify how you created the domain? (You don't need to do this manually).
Are you able to start the integrated WebLogic at all?
If not try to remove the defaultDomain directory from the JDeveloper System folder.

Comment: I created domain using Tools->configuration wizard

Answer (score 0):

I uninstall the jdeveloper and installed it again....I didnot create domain using configuration wizard....and it is working now.
The below site gives required information about configuration of integrated weblogic server
 **https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/lcm/SOAQS/SOA-INTEGRATING.htm#SOAQS475**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the environment variables are set properly. For eg)

```
setenv JAVA_HOME /ade_autofs/gd29_3rdparty/JDK6_MAIN_LINUX.X64.rdd/121114.1.6.0.38.0B05/jdk6
```

If it doesn't work, try removing the default domain directory. It is generally located inside the view, in .jdev_user_home with name as systemxx.x.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem.Tried different methods but failed. In worst case delete folder containing jdeveloper. Go to AppData->Roaming->Jdeveloper .Delete the folder "system11.1.1.7.40.66.61.3". Go to control panel and uninstall "Oracle fusion Middleware 11.1.1.x.x".
Freshly install jdeveloper again and start the server instance.